# Document viewer using local files

Tags: php, document

I develop a kind of emailbox using PHP on a local server. I get attachments, so I want to display them in a viewer because my users are not familiar with files and how opening them.
The Google Doc viewer is great, but I cannot use local files.. I search for a lot a solutions (Applet, SWF), but I don't find anything.
Is there a way to display local files into a nice viewer ? (for images, ZIP files, PDF...)